# What is the number of $0\leq j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_n\leq v-1$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}j_i\equiv 0 \mod v$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, modular-arithmetic

In the title, $v$ is an integer such that $v>1$.

Comment: @David Ooops, I meant for the case $n=3$. Corrected now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is incorrect.  The number of possibilities is simply $v^{n-1}$.  Reason: we can choose anything we like from the $v$ available values for $j_1,\ldots,j_{n-1}$, and then there is exactly one value of $j_n$ which will make the sum $0$ modulo $v$.

To correct your calculation: how many  options are there with $n=3$ and sum $v$?

- If $j_1=0$ then $j_2=1,2,\ldots,v-1$ and there is one option for $j_3$: total, $v-1$.
- If $j_1=1$ then $j_2=0,1,\ldots,v-1$ and there is one option for $j_3$: total, $v$.
- If $j_1=2$ then $j_2=0,1,\ldots,v-2$ and there is one option for $j_3$: total, $v-1$.
- and so on, giving
  $$(v-1)+\bigl[v+(v-1)+(v-2)+\cdots+2\bigr]=\frac{(v-1)(v+4)}{2}\ .$$

Your other calculations are correct, giving a total of
$$1+\frac{(v-1)(v+4)}{2}+\frac{(v-1)(v-2)}{2}=v^2\ .$$

Comment: So, I was not careful again. In my original question I needed to put that $1 \leq  \j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_n\leq v-1$. I accepted your answer because it is correct for the question I asked and may prove to be helpful to others. 

On top of that, I think I can work on a proof by using your idea. In particular, for the case $n=3$, we have $v^2$ tuples including the cases when any of $j_1,j_2,j_3$ are $0$, and then we subtract the cases that $j_1+j_2\equiv 0 \bmod v$. Then we end up having (v-1)(v-2).

I think this should be an easy application of the inclusion-exclusion principle.. I'll work on it.

Comment: If you would like to ask that question, I will answer it ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Using your answer here it was fairly simple to get a recursive formula: If $N_n$ is the number question (with the $j$'s being $>0$, then it seems that $N_n=(v-1)^{n-1} - N_{n-1}$. I did it a bit quickly but it should be right. From that I think I'll be able to get a formula.

Comment: Having found that recurrence, all you will need to do is sum a geometric progression.

Comment: Yup, should be quite easy. Maybe change a bit for n odd or even..